# iOS RotatingWheelProject exception error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, exception

I'm trying to implement the RotatingWhellProject I've found on

http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit

I'm very new to iOS development and this is actually my first app :)
When I built the project, I had some errors and I fixed them but in runtime I'm having the error below:

```
2012-04-24 10:58:21.436 RotaryWheelProject[4122:207] -[NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b19370
2012-04-24 10:58:21.439 RotaryWheelProject[4122:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b19370'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

It is not hard to understand that I'm having an exception error which I'm not handling but I don't seem to understand where?

There was a line I corrected from

```
@autorelease{return main(something..)}
```

to just return `main(something)`

Help appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` is a method of [`NSFastEnumeration`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSFastEnumeration_protocol/Reference/NSFastEnumeration.html) protocol. `NSString` doesn't implement this protocol, while other things such as `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` and `NSSet` do.

Check your code to see who is calling `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` (should be an NSString object) and ensure it is the right object with a valid type which implements the protocol.